# print specific INFILE area using perl

Tags: perl

I have a file with the format below

```
locale,English,en_AU,6251
locale,French,fr_BE,25477
charmap,English,EN,5423
```

And I would like to use perl to print out something with the option "-a" follows by the file and outputs something like

```
Available locales:
en_Au
fr_BE
EN
```

To do that, I have the perl script below

```
$o = $ARGV[0];
$f = $ARGV[1];
open (INFILE, "<$f") or die "error";
my $line = <INFILE>;
my @fields = split(',', $line);
if($o eq "-a"){
  if(!$fields[2]){print "No locales available\n";}
  else{print "Available locales: \n";
    while($fields[2]){print "$fields[2]\n";}
  }
}
close(INFILE);
```

And I have three questions here.
1. my script will only print the first locale "en_Au" forever.
2. it should be able to test if a file is empty, but if a file is purely empty, it outputs nothing, but if I type in two empty lines in the file, it prints two lines of "No locales available" instead.
3.In fact in the (!$filed[2]) part I should verify if the file is empty or no available locales exist, if so do I need to put some regular expression here to verify if it is a locale as well??
Hope someone could help me figure these out! Many thanks!!!

Comment: The code reads only one line, `my $line = <INFILE>;`.  It needs a loop, in which reads one line after another, `while (my $line = <INFILE>) { ... }` The rest seems fine.  But, why not just skip the line if it doesn't have the third field?  (Is that really a good condition?) Like `next if not $fields[2];`.  Then, the whole thing needs to be rewritten in modern Perl.

Comment: Every time through the loop you can store the needed field in an array, and print it all after the loop.  Or, of course, you can print them as you find them on each line.  (The `while` loop over `$fields[2]` in the code doesn't make sense.)

Comment: @zdim Hi zdim, I tried use while at the beginning, but it keeps outputing "en_AU"

Comment: Posted an answer, but I don't understand some of the explanation of what you need.  Let me know how it goes

Answer (score 4):

The biggest missing thing is a loop over lines from the file, in which you then process one line at a time. Comments follow the code.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Getopt::Long;

#my ($opt, $file) = @ARGV;  # better use a module
my ($opt, $file);
Getoptions( 'a' => \$opt, 'file=s' => \$file ) or usage();
usage() if not $file;  # mandatory argument    

open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @fields = split /,/, $line;
    next if not $fields[2];
    if ($opt) {
        say $fields[2];
    }   
}
close $fh;

sub usage {
    say STDERR "Usage: $0 [-a] --file filename";
    exit 1;
}
```

This prints the desired output. (Is that simple condition on `$fields[2]` really all you need?)

Comments

- Always have `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the beginning
- I do not recommend single-letter variable names.  One forgets what they mean, it makes the code harder to follow, and it's way too easy to make silly mistakes
- The `@ARGV` can be assigned to variables in a list. Much better, use [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) module, which checks invocation and allows for far easier interface changes. I set the `-a` option to act as a "flag," so it just sets a variable (`$opt`) if it's given. If that should have possible values instead, use `'a=s' => \$opt` and check for a value.
- Use lexical filehandles and the three-argument [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html), `open my $fh, '<', $file ...`
- When `die`-ing print *the error*, `die "... $!";`, using [`$!` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables)
- The ["diamond" (angle) operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators), `<$fh>`, reads *one line* from a file opened with `$fh` when used in [scalar context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context), as in `$line = <$fh>`.  It advances a pointer in the file as it reads a line so the next time it's used it returns the next line. If you use it in *list context* then it returns all lines, but when you process a file you normally want to go line by line.

Some of the described logic and requirements aren't clear to me, but hopefully the code above is going to be easier to adjust as needed.